# Change from background thread to main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I create a new thread so the operation is running on the background thread:

```
void ProcessCall(char *szJSON)
{       
    #ifdef _WIN32
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ProcessOnNewThread, szJSON, 0, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
        hThread = NULL;
    #endif
}

namespace callEventCallbacks
{
   void OnEventDetected(const char *szEvent)
   {
        // Make sure the callback function is specified
        if (callEventInterface.ProcessCallBackJSInterfaceResponse == NULL)
           return;

        if (!strcmp(szEvent, "EVENT_DETECTED"))
           iOLibInterface.ProcessCallBackJSInterfaceResponse (szEventDetectedCallback, NULL, 0);
   }
}

namespace
{   
    DWORD WINAPI ProcessOnNewThread(LPVOID lpvParam)
    {
         // Obtain the string JSON from the parameter
         char *szJSON = (char *)lpvParam;

        // Attempt to parse the JSON to rapidjson Document structure - this allocates memory for the json document, the string can be freed after parsing it
        Document jsonDocument;
        bool validJson = !jsonDocument.Parse<0>(szJSON).HasParseError();

        // Obtain the parameters from the JSON based on the operation type
        if (!strcmp(szOperation, "RegisterForCardEvent"))
        {
            if (jsonDocument.HasMember("EventName") && jsonDocument.HasMember("Callback"))
            {
                 // Obtain the event name and callback function name
                const char *szEvent = jsonDocument["EventName"].GetString();
                const char *szCallback = jsonDocument["Callback"].GetString();

                 // Store the callback in a required buffer and register the callback for a required card event
                 if (!strcmp(szEvent, "EVENT_DETECTED"))
                 {
                     SPRINTF_S(callEventCallbacks::szEventDetectedCallback, sizeof(callEventCallbacks::szEventDetectedCallback), szCallback);
                     callEvent.RegisterForCardEvent(callEventCallbacks::OnEventDetected);
                  }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Then I want to switch the background thread to the main thread and continue the operation: (Have the switch statement run on the main thread instead of the background thread)

```
namespace
{
    CJSCallDoc *globalDocument;
    void ProcessCallBackJSInterfaceResponse (const char *szCallback, const char **arrayOfParameters, int arraySize)
    {
        switch (arraySize)
        {
        case 0:
            globalDocument->m_webPage.CallJScript(szCallback);
            break;
        case 1:
            globalDocument->m_webPage.CallJScript(szCallback, arrayOfParameters[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            globalDocument->m_webPage.CallJScript(szCallback, arrayOfParameters[0], arrayOfParameters[1]);
            break;
        case 3:
            globalDocument->m_webPage.CallJScript(szCallback, arrayOfParameters[0], arrayOfParameters[1], arrayOfParameters[2]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how this could be done, and would be able to give me an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, if you want a background thread to trigger an action on the GUI thread, the most common thing is to post or send a custom windows message to the main thread's message queue and react to that.

PostMessage is asynchronous, so the background thread will not wait for completion, while SendMessage is synchronous.

Comment: How would I gather the response from the PostMessage or the SendMessage?

Comment: In the case of SendMessage, you can either use the return value directly, or put an out pointer in the arguments you pass along. In the case of PostMessage, you wouldn't; instead the main thread would start a new unit of work based on its results. Note that starting a new thread for every background action is very inefficient; usually you would have a thread pool and post tasks to the pool.